# will "adb reboot" command saves the state of the device before rebooting

Tags: android

Whenever we do power-off or reboot the state of the device will be saved.
Will the same happens if I reboot/power-off the device using below adb commands:

1. adb reboot --> reboot device
2. adb reboot -p --> power off the device

Answer (score 0):

`adb reboot` does not operate on device directly. It asks OS to perform reboot or power off procedure. See the [sources of adb](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/services.c#115).

So, it will not result as removing the battery from your device. It should be similar to rebooting your device normally.